# Change detection in complex system

Tags: sql, .net, change-tracking

This might seem like a fairly specific question but I'm wondering if there is any technology/pattern out there that might help me in a current project.  I have a hugely complex database which is updated by multiple systems.  I now need to do change tracking on various bits of data that is spread across multiple tables so that I can send it to a third party system.

I've considered a number of options but unfortunately I can't seem to come to any other conclusion than using database triggers.  I'm thinking of storing a flag in a table (or queue) to identify the rows that have changed and then building an xml diff containing the changed data to send to a web service.  This feels a little dirty so I was wondering if anyone could think of a better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the database platform you're using, you might look into Change Data Capture.  Since you mention .NET, here's some info about it:  [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489(v=sql.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Other database systems may offer something similar.

Another option would be insert/update/delete triggers on the tables, however triggers should be approached carefully as they can cause some significant performance problems if not done right.

And yet another option still would be what you describe - some sort of flag to monitor for changes.  A simple CREATED and MODIFIED timestamp fields can go a long way here, as rather than just a bit indicator suggesting that the row may need attention, you'll know when the update happened, and your export process can be programmed accordingly (e.g., select * from table where modified > getdate()-1).